# MouseArea fails to update mouseContains property when moved

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

I have an issue where the **MouseArea**'s **containMouse** property doesn't correctly update itself after being animated.

Below I've included a code snippet that hopefully will illustrate my point:

```
import QtQuick 2.10

Item {
    id: root

    width: 500
    height: 240
    visible: true

    ListView {
        id: view

        anchors.fill: parent
        anchors.margins: 20
        orientation: ListView.Horizontal
        spacing: 20

        delegate: Rectangle {
            width: 100
            height: 200
            color: "black"
            radius: 10

            Rectangle {
                width: 40
                height: 40
                anchors.centerIn: parent
                color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "white" : "grey"
                visible: model.index == view.currentIndex

                MouseArea {
                    id: mouseArea

                    anchors.fill: parent
                    hoverEnabled: true

                    onClicked: view.model.move(view.currentIndex, view.currentIndex+1, 1)
                }
            }
        }

        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { number: 1 }
            ListElement { number: 2 }
            ListElement { number: 3 }
            ListElement { number: 4 }
        }

        move: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x"; duration: 200 }
        }

        moveDisplaced: Transition {
            NumberAnimation { properties: "x"; duration: 200 }
        }
    }
}
```

If you were to run this application, you would be presented with the following display:

[image: Application startup screenshot]

Moving your cursor to the bottom left portion of the grey box would change the box color to white, as such:

[image: Hover over first box]

The moment you click on the button, an animation is triggered to swap the **ListView**'s first and second element around. Upon completion, unfortunately, you **MIGHT** get the following result:

[image: Results of clicking the box]

Based on the code line `color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "white" : "grey"`, I would have expected the rectangle to be grey, as the mouse is no longer contained in the **MouseArea**.

So my question is:

1. Is there something wrong with my code
2. Is this a bug
3. What can be done to correct this behaviour
4. Maybe an explanation as to why this happens

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is the instruction:

```
visible: model.index == view.currentIndex
```

When the element is moved, that instruction varies between True and False, so it is considered unstable in the transition, which is why it generates that undefined behavior. `ListView` provides a stable property called [`ListView.isCurrentItem`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#isCurrentItem-attached-prop) that indicates the current item.

The solution is the next:

```
delegate: Rectangle {
    id: rect // <--- set id
    width: 100
    height: 200
    color: "black"
    radius: 10

    Rectangle {
        width: 40
        height: 40
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: mouseArea.containsMouse ? "white" : "grey"
        visible: rect.ListView.isCurrentItem // <--- change this line
        MouseArea {
            id: mouseArea

            anchors.fill: parent
            hoverEnabled: true

            onClicked: view.model.move(view.currentIndex, view.currentIndex+1, 1)
        }
    }
}
```